# Optimizing the OpenGL ES settings for 2D drawing

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm experimenting with using OpenGL ES to draw rather complicated paths, as I was running into severe performance problems when using the generic Android drawing functions. So far using OpenGL directly seems to be significantly faster, but I'm wondering about the difference between drawing in 2D as compared to 3D.

I'm using [the example from the Google Tutorial on OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html), and modified it a bit to remove the third dimension from my vertices. Just omitting the z coordinate in `glVertexAttribPointer` and passing 2 as the size parameter seems to work. This seems to be an obvious and easy optimization, and it also makes the code a bit clearer. But I'm wondering at which other places OpenGL ES just assumes 3D, and does unnecessary work.

For example, I don't need any depth testing, but from what I read it isn't clear to me if just never explicitly enabling it is enough, or if I need to disable any settings?

I'm not looking for microoptimizations, but for general settings that remove assumptions that I'm working in 3D and simplify or remove calculations that just are not necessary in 2D. What are other things I should do when I'm working in pure 2D, and not in 3D?

Comment: If you are in for some digging you could check https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/ and see how they did it. Or just use the framework in the first place...